# How can I convert hex2int?

Tags: c, integer, hex, ansi-c

I have a problem I tried to convert 600ca025 from hex to int but what i got was \f`0ca025. I used sscanf whit "\x", what else can I do? I run a debug and right this line with sscanf is the problem to be precise.

Comment: `\x` isn't a valid format string for *anything*. not surprised it  didn't work. Did you [check the `scanf` docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and specifically the format specifiers, to understand how they work?

Answer (score 1):

The scanf format for hex is not `\x`. It is `%x`.

`scanf("%x", &variable_name);`